# Accessing host different ports in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, vue.js, frontend, backend

I'm making an app with Vue.js as frontend and Rails as backend, everything running with docker on development and production.

in development, I can access the services with localhost:8080 (front end) and make request to the backend URL with localhost:5678 (rails port).

but when I deploy this to production, which has a domain name([www.websiteurl.com](http://www.websiteurl.com)), I can view the front end but can't access the backend, I am unable to make any request.

I try to make requests to [www.websiteurl.com:5678](http://www.websiteurl.com:5678) and nothing happens, how can I access the backend port with a domain name?

ps1: I'm sorry if the question is not clear enough, feel free to ask anything
ps2: I have correctly set up CORS access on the backend
ps3: if I access the production server via IP, it works correctly, the problem is when I access via the domain name

Update:
Command used to run front-end:

```
docker build -t runaterra:ekko .
docker run -d \
    -w /runaterra-ekko/ \
    -p 80:8080 \
    --name ekko \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    runaterra:ekko npm run dev
```

Command used to run backend:

```
docker-compose up -d --restart unless-stopped db
docker-compose build app
docker-compose run --rm app rake db:migrate
docker-compose up -d --restart unless-stopped app
```

Comment: Could you add the docker commands you're using to run your container's image please?

Comment: You probably have a firewall issue, make sure port `5678` is open and pass through on your server

Comment: I updated the questions with the commands, i will check if the port is open

Answer (score 1):

You didn't expose port 5678 of your app to the internet.

Comment: Thanks, i was about to answer this myself